# Generic Activator.CreateInstance with different parameters

Tags: c#

I have the following factory class:

```
    public class ApiClientFactory
    {
        private readonly IProxyManager _proxyManager;


        public ApiClientFactory(IProxyManager proxyManager)
        {
            _proxyManager = proxyManager;
        }

        public IAPIClient CreateApiClient(Type t)
        {
            try
            {
                IAPIClient apiClient = (IAPIClient) Activator.CreateInstance(t, _proxyManager);
                return apiClient;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have classes defined such as:

```
public class DemoApiClient : IAPIClient
{
    public DemoApiClient(IProxyManager proxyManager, DeviceInformation deviceInformation)
    {
        ///
    }

    public IProxyManager ProxyManager { get; }
    public IHTTPClient HttpClient { get; }
}

public class DemoApiClient2 : IAPIClient
{
    public DemoApiClient2(IProxyManager proxyManager)
    {
        ///
    }

    public IProxyManager ProxyManager { get; }
    public IHTTPClient HttpClient { get; }
}
```

How can I rework my factory class to be generic, so that it can accept constructor parameters for different classes? i.e. `DemoApiClient` constructor needs `IProxyManager` AND `DeviceInformation`, however `DemoApiClient2` only needs `IProxyManager`.

Note that these are only two examples, there might be situations where there are no parameters required, and other situations where there might more than what I've listed here.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a dependency injection framework. Or are you sure you want to roll your own?

Comment: I would like to do it without a library, so I can learn :)